# Search requests timing out with concurrent transactions in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Apologies here in advance for this non-simplified use case.

During one of my data load processes, concurrent request transactions are used to fill MarkLogic.

Each concurrent thread does the following operations at a high level:

```
1) Create a transaction via the transactions API

2) Search if a certain document exists passing in transaction ID from step 1. (could possibly search for a document being updated and locked in another concurrent transaction with another transaction ID. It is with this query that is timing out)

3) If document does not exist, create new document with transaction
ID from step 1, if it does exist, upsert new document with transaction ID from step 1.

4) Commit transaction from step 1.
```

Deadlocks are occurring here with this process, which we see in the error logs, which we are fine with, if any requests get deadlocked, we push them to the bottom of the queue to retry. An issue we are running into is we have `cts:search()` queries that timeout, causing our concurrent transaction process to lengthen exponentially, rather than throwing a deadlock retryable error right away, which is what we expect.

Below is a sample request that is timing out to the server:

This is a POST to the /v1/search endpoint, which just does a basic unfiltered path-range-query that we have an index for, as well as a json-property-value query.

```
cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:and-query((cts:collection-query(\"my_collection\"), cts:path-range-query(\"/structure/id\", \"=\", \"28820425\", (\"collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/\"), 1), cts:json-property-value-query(\"@class\", \"myClass\", (\"lang=en\"), 1)), ()), (\"unfiltered\", cts:score-order(\"descending\")), xs:double(\"0\"), ())
```

And we get the follow timeout error:

> {"errorResponse":{"statusCode":500, "status":"Internal Server Error", "messageCode":"INTERNAL ERROR", "message":"SVC-EXTIME:

When debugging, we do see concurrently when this transaction is being run, documents returned in the `cts:search` are locked for updates in other transactions.

Why is our `cts:search` returning a timeout error here, is the request hanging because certain documents are locked? When explicitly locking documents in our testing and then searching for them, all the documents still get returned with a valid search response without error or a timeout.

Our dataset is not large (3k documents) and our documents are even smaller (10-15 JSON fields), so performance can't be the issue here.

Is there any options we can set here to help on the appserver itself? Or structure our query differently? Any explanation would help greatly here. Sorry again for not being able to provide a testable case, but just curious if anyone has run into something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When debugging, we do see concurrently when this transaction is being run, documents returned in the `cts:search` are locked for updates in other transactions. **We are well aware of this possibility and are okay with it.**

You may **think** that you are okay with it, but you are running into performance issues that are likely due to it, and are looking to avoid timeouts - **so you probably aren't okay with it**.

When you perform a search in an update transaction, all of the fragments will get a `read-lock`. You can have multiple transactions all obtain read locks on the same URI without a problem. However, if one of those transactions then decides it wants to update one of those documents, it needs to promote it's shared `read-lock` to an exclusive `write-lock`. When that happens, all of those other transactions that had a `read-lock` on that URI will get restarted. If they need access to that URI that has an exclusive `write-lock` then they will have to wait until the transaction that has the `write-lock` completes and lets go.

So, if you have a lot of competing transactions all performing searches with the same criteria and trying to snag the first item (or first set of items) from the search results, they can cause each other to keep restarting and/or waiting, which takes time. Adding more threads in an attempt to do more makes it even worse.

There are several strategies that you can use to avoid this lock contention.

Instead of `cts:search()` to search and retrieve the documents, you could use `cts:uris()`, and then before reading the doc with `fn:doc()` (which would first obtain a `read-lock`) before attempting to UPSERT (which would promote the `read-lock` to a `write-lock`), you could use `xdmp:lock-for-update()` on the URI to obtain an exclusive `write-lock` and then read the doc with `fn:doc()`.

If you are trying to perform some sort of batch processing, using a tool such as [CoRB](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2) to first query for the set of URIs to process (lock-free) in a read-only transaction, and then fire off lots of worker transactions to process each URI separately where it reads/locks the doc without any contention.

You could also separate the search and update work, using `xdmp:invoke-function()` or `xdmp:spawn-function()` so that the search is executed lock-free and the update work is isolated.

Some resources that describe locks and performance issues caused by lock contention:

- https://www.marklogic.com/blog/resolving-unresolvable-deadlocks/
- https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17/0/understanding-xdmp-deadlock
- https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/understanding-locking-in-marklogic-using-examples
- https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/strategies-to-ensure-if-locking-is-the-root-cause-for-performance-degradation-in-marklogic

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mads, based off the type of queries we are running here, it's sounding like we will need to spin up a custom endpoint to set up transparent locking and releasing. We are just using the OOB REST API's right now for all our operations (v1/search, v1/documents, v1/transactions). Knowing our use case would there by a way to seperate locks with those endpoints? Or do you suggest spinning up a REST extension that would invoke the logic using your suggestions?

Comment: It's a little difficult to reason about and make recommendations without knowing more about how you are calling things. I don't have much practical experience using v1/transactions and making many calls as a multi-statement transaction. Do you need all the work to be done atomically? Could you reduce to smaller sets of work? Maybe share more of the code or logic flow in the Support case that you have opened and MarkLogic Support may be able to give better suggestions and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand fully what the issue is, this is the clue to follow:

> When debugging, we do see concurrently when this transaction is being run, documents returned in the cts:search are locked for updates in other transactions.

Find out what transactions correspond to which documents, and where in your code this transaction is being created (implicitly or explicitly).

The goal is to *never have deadlocks* -- yes they are recoverable sometimes, but should be considered a bug that needs to be fixed not trapped as a normal means.

Generally, to avoid these issues one must:

Not hold open a transaction (explicitly or implicitly) which does a search or loop and has any path that might also do an update.  Find a way to validate if you should update/insert via the doc URI not via a search or loop.

Avoid using the transaction REST endpoint -- instead implement single 'queries' (either adhoc or stored xquery/js modules ) that do a single atomic update on a single document without even looking at other documents.   The problem with the REST transaction is the server does not know how long its supposed to last so has to resort to server timeouts to 'detect' client bugs.  E.g. if your client throws an exception the server doesn't know to abort the transaction so will keep it open a long time.  If the code is running in the server (xquery/js) then transaction *along with all the code executing with it* are aborted.

Split search/update into independent tasks with their own transactions not inheriting their parents by using one of the spawn API's (via  REST or otherwise)
Call these *asynchronously* so that they do not in turn cause deadlocks by blocking the caller transaction.